# Bevy - Have multiple Sprites Sheets per Entity

Tags: bevy

I have a Entity containing a Srite Sheet and class instance

```rs
let texture_handle = asset_server.load("turret_idle.png");
let texture_atlas: TextureAtlas = TextureAtlas::from_grid(texture_handle, ...);
let texture_atlas_handle = texture_atlases.add(texture_atlas);
let mut turret = Turret::create(...);
commands.spawn_bundle(SpriteSheetBundle {
    texture_atlas: texture_atlas_handle,
    transform: Transform::from_xyz(pos),
    ..default()
})
.insert(turret)
.insert(AnimationTimer(Timer::from_seconds(0.04, true)));
```

The AnimationTimer will then be used in a query together with the Texture Atlas Handle to render the next sprite

```rs
fn animate_turret(
    time: Res<Time>,
    texture_atlases: Res<Assets<TextureAtlas>>,
    mut query: Query<(
        &mut AnimationTimer,
        &mut TextureAtlasSprite,
        &Handle<TextureAtlas>,
    )>,
) {
    for (mut timer, mut sprite, texture_atlas_handle) in &mut query {
        timer.tick(time.delta());
        if timer.just_finished() {
            let texture_atlas = texture_atlases.get(texture_atlas_handle).unwrap();
            sprite.index = (sprite.index + 1) % texture_atlas.textures.len();
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine as long as the tower is idle thus plays the idle animation. As soon as a target is found and attacked, I want to display another sprite sheet instead.

```rs
let texture_handle_attack = asset_server.load("turret_attack.png");
```

Unfortunately, It seems that I cannot add multiple TextureAtlas Handles to a Sprite Sheet Bundle and decide later which one to render. How do I solve this? I thought about merging all animations into one Sprite Sheet already but this is very messy as they have different frames.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a struct with all the different handles you need and add it as a resource? Then you need a component for the enum states "idle", "attacked" etc.. and a system that handles setting the correct handle in `texture_atlas` from your resource handles.